# Draw an image in a Picture Control

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a picture control which is called `IDC_PICTURECONTROL`, and a `LPPICTURE` which is called `lpPicutre`.

When my window receives `WM_PAINT`, I call my function `drawPicture(HWND, LPPICTURE)` like this:

```
drawPicture(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_PICTURECONTROL), lpPicture);
```

The way it is written now, the black border around the control just disappears and the picture is not drawn at all.

If I edit the function so that it's not drawing to the picture control, but rather the dialog itself (`hDlg`), then it is correctly drawn on the background of the window's client area. (Not what I want).

Here is the code in the paint function:

```
void drawPicture(HWND hWnd, LPPICTURE picture)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
  //hdc = BeginPaint(hDlg, &ps); (works, but draws on window instead of control)

    if (picture)
    {
        long hmWidth;
        long hmHeight;
        picture->get_Width(&hmWidth);
        picture->get_Height(&hmHeight);

        int nWidth  = MulDiv(hmWidth,  GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX), HIMETRIC_INCH);
        int nHeight = MulDiv(hmHeight, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), HIMETRIC_INCH);

        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc); // I have tried GetWindowRect() also

        int w = 0, h = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
        if (hmWidth == hmHeight)
        {
            // square
            w = (rc.right - rc.left);
            h = (rc.bottom - rc.top);

            x = rc.left;
            y = rc.top;
        }
        else if (hmWidth > hmHeight)
        {
            // wide
            w = (rc.right - rc.left);
            h = (w * hmHeight) / hmWidth;

            x = rc.left;
            y = (rc.bottom - rc.top - h) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            //tall
            h = (rc.bottom - rc.top);
            w = (h * hmWidth) / hmHeight;

            y = rc.top;
            x = (rc.right - rc.left - w) / 2;
        }

        picture->Render(hdc, x, y, w, h, 0, hmHeight, hmWidth, -hmHeight, &rc);
    }

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
  //EndPaint(hDlg, &ps);
}
```

`hWnd` is the handler to the picture control, and `hDlg` is the handler to the dialog.

I thought maybe it's being drawn off the window somewhere, so I set the x and y to 0, and the width and height to 1000, but this did not change anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is working with hDlg, it is OK and the problem is probably in the static control itself. Ensure that is has SS_BITMAP style. In Visual Studio resource editor it is called Type and set to SS_BLACKFRAME (Frame) by default.

Answer (score 0):

This code does working for CStatic.

```
CPictureView* image = new CPictureView(std::string("E:\\My Documents\\..jpeg"));
image->Create("", SS_BLACKRECT | SS_OWNERDRAW | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(100, 100, 300, 300), this, IDC_STATIC1);
```